# Is it possible to put Google Play on Windows Phone

Tags: google

I was wondering if it is possible to put Google Play on a Windows Lumia phone?

Answer (score 7):

**No. Its not possible, unless its totally wiping the phone and flashing onto it an android operating system.**

[Google Play](http://play.google.com) is a marketplace specific to the the [Android OS Ecosystem](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) and its variants.

Windows Phone and Windows 10 Mobile (which is the OS on Lumia Phones) are not android based Operating Systems, so no android apps can run on this platform.

For the Lumias, you have the [Microsoft Store](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows-phone) as the official apps and media distribution for the platform.

You can read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mobile_operating_systems) for more clarity on the differences of the current mobile operating systems

Answer (score 3):

**Google Play** is an Android app marketplace where you can find Android-only apps. Because of this **it's not available for neither Windows nor iOS.**

Answer (score -1):

Simply No, there is way to run google play in any windows operated mobile phone. Google play is only run in microsoft XL because this is the android operated on windows theme mobile presented by microsoft.

Comment: What is "microsoft XL"?

Comment: Microsoft old mobile phone in which they introduce android framework with windows phone theme.

Comment: Do you mean the [Nokia X series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_X_family)?